# Numpy element-wise isin for two 2d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, isin

I have two arrays:

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])

b = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 3, 3],
              [1, 2, 4, 5, 9],
              [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

The expected output would match the shape of array 'a' and would be:

```py
array([True, False], [False, True], [True, False])
```

The first dimension size of arrays a and b always matches (in this case 3).

What I wish to calculate is for each index of each array (0 to 2 as there are 3 dimensions here) is if each number in the array 'a' exists in the corresponding second dimension of array 'b'.

I can solve this in a loop with the following code, but I would like to vectorise it to gain a speed boost but having sat here for several hours, I cannot figure it out:

```py
output = np.full(a.shape, False)
assert len(a) == len(b)
for i in range(len(a)):
    output[i] = np.isin(a[i], b[i])
```

Thank you for any guidance! Anything would be very appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properly reshape the arrays so they can broadcast correctly while comparing:

```
(a[...,None] == b[:,None]).any(2)

#[[ True False]
# [False  True]
# [ True False]]
```

- `a[...,None]` adds an extra dimension to the end, with shape `(3, 2, 1)`;
- `b[:,None]` inserts a dimension as 2nd axis, with shape `(3, 1, 5)`;
- When you compare the two arrays, both will be broadcasted to `(3, 2, 5)` so essentially you compare each element in the row of `a` to each element in the corresponding row of `b`;
- finally you can check if there's any match for every element in `a`;

Comment: This worked perfectly and a beautiful explanation, thanks! Think this has really helped me grasp slicing/indexing with elipsis and colon operators :) It's just funny how my pycharm linter complains I can't call any() on a bool object. Haha. It doesn't realise numpy returns an array and not a bool.